# Upgrading Mongo to 3.x; insert no longer returns WriteResult

Tags: java, mongodb, migration

We are upgrading our Mongo from version 2.x to 3.x, and I am given the task of updating our old (Java) code to the new version of everything, trying to avoid deprecated methods but otherwise trying to change functionality as little as possible. I did not write the original version of the code.

The following change I find confusing. Before, we used `DBCollection.insert(args)` which returned a `WriteResult` object. Now we should use `MongoCollection.insertOne(args)`, but this returns nothing. Is there another way to produce a `WriteResult` object?

Or is the opinion of the Mongo dev team that `WriteResult` objects are not necessary? I can see that we are using it in a fairly inessential way (just logging) but I don't want to remove it without good reason.

All the above also applies to `insertMany`, and I assume it would have the same or similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

`insertOne()` method gives some advantages to handle the problematic situations where as `insert` required some manual checks, for e.g

1.)   it support `Error Handling` mean you have to use your insert code in `try-catch` block which simply can tell you , something went wrong (like inserting duplicate entries for unique indexes)so do something else instead of current flow.

**InsertOne Returns** :

> - void : mean successful completion of query
> - Exception : Various exceptions are thrown which represent the different-2 cause for failure insertion as

```
MongoWriteException - if the write failed due some other failure specific to the insert command
MongoWriteConcernException - if the write failed due being unable to fulfill the write concern
MongoException - if the write failed due some other failure
```

So you can simply add three catch blocks to handle all possibilities of insertion failure and if no exception is thrown mean data inserted successfully (no need to check anything , move on quickly ) and code will be like

```
try {
   .. insert query
   }catch(MongoWriteException  e){ .. handle something wrong with query}
    catch(MongoWriteConcernException e){ .. handle something wrong with write-concern}
    catch(MongoException e){ .. handle something else(unknown) went wrong}
```

Consultation : You will get

- `try-catch` a good practice result in less problematic code

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, very helpful - I see how the exception throwing obviates need for WriteResult in many cases. However I'm confused about at least one point in your answer, saying "insertOne returns ..." when insertOne has return type `void`. Is there some sense in which `insertOne` returns something? How do I get at the value?

Comment: @RichardRast your welcome ,check out this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/) , insertOne will return a document containing acknowledgment and id , void may only occur in case of some exception but still the `e` will give you the desired details about exception

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? In the Java API, the return type of the method is void.

Comment: @RichardRast oops , that is pure mongo db but don't worry , the things are almost same and yeah it's return void because in case of an error i( not inserted , due to unfulfill write concern or etc ) will throw an exception so you can handle in different-2 catch block  and if no error mean success , letme update this content in answer

Comment: edit history will be helpful in case somebody wants to know the standalone mongodb implementation :P:)