# MongoDB check insertion

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, jdbc

I controll data inserted or not inserted in mysql as follows

```
public boolean addUser(User user) throws Exception {

    boolean isRegister=false;

    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    try{

        String sql="insert into users(username,email,pasword) values(?,?,?)";

        conn=dataSource.getConnection();

        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, user.getUsername());
        ps.setString(2, kullanici.getEmail());
        ps.setString(3, kullanici.getPassword());

        int success=ps.executeUpdate();

        if(success>0){
            isRegister=true;
        }

        return isRegister;
    }finally{
        baglantiSonlandir(conn, null, ps);
    }


}
```

How can I achieve this process in MongoDB?
I wrote some code but I didn't achieve that data is inserted or not inserted to db.My MongoDb code is bellow;

```
public boolean addUser(User user) throws Exception {

    boolean isRegister=false;

    MongoClient client=null;
    MongoDatabase database=null;

    try{

        client=new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        database=client.getDatabase("ogryonsis");

        MongoCollection collection=database.getCollection("users");

        Document document=new Document();
        document.put("username", user.getUserName());
        document.put("email", user.getEmail());
        document.put("password", user.getPassword());

        collection.insertOne(document);

        //int success ->I didnt find for here appropriate code  

        if(success>0){
            isRegister=true;
        }

        return isRegister;
    }finally{
        client.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: since insertone returns void so  there is no way and if no exception is thrown than you can assume that data has been written successfully, for further reading try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137495/upgrading-mongo-to-3-x-insert-no-longer-returns-writeresult/40138542#40138542)

Answer (score 2):

As writen in documentation, if the write fails, you will get `MongoWriteConcernException` or `MongoWriteException`

You can adapt your code like this:

```
isRegister=true;
try {
  collection.insertOne(document);
  }
  catch (MongoServerException ex {
    isRegister=false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `insertOne` is defined as void method. The ideal way is to wrap the `insertOne` statement in try-catch block. Obviously, the insert is unsuccessful if there is any exception.

> MongoWriteException - if the write failed due some other failure
>   specific to the insert command MongoWriteConcernException - if the
>   write failed due being unable to fulfil the write concern
>   MongoException - if the write failed due some other failure

If you are using Spring, you could perform this.

```
MongoOperations mongoOperations = getMongoConnection();

        try {
            mongoOperations.insert(order);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException de) {
            de.printStackTrace();
        }
```